# how to get applied ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

i have build one specific function through coding. this is my code :

```
public static string GetRefNo()
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            string tickPrefix = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.TicketPrefix).SingleOrDefault();
            int xyear = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Last_Login_Datetime.Value.Year).SingleOrDefault();
            int xmonth = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Last_Login_Datetime.Value.Month).SingleOrDefault();
            int xday = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Last_Login_Datetime.Value.Day).SingleOrDefault();
            int xcounter = int.Parse(db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Counter).SingleOrDefault().ToString());
            xcounter++;
            var query = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u).ToList();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    db.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE [CRM].[dbo].[tbl_User_master] SET [Counter] = {0} WHERE Ref_no = {1}", xcounter, item.Ref_no);
                }
            }
             return tickPrefix + xyear.ToString().Substring(3, 1) + xmonth.ToString() ? 0.PadLeft(2, '0') + xday.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + xcounter.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
        }
    }
```

now i just want to check if `xmonth.ToString()` is less than 10 then just apply this `PadLeft(2, '0')` else simple `xmonth.ToString()`.

please help me....

Comment: Why don't you simply use `xmonth.ToString("00");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static string GetRefNo()
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            string tickPrefix = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.TicketPrefix).SingleOrDefault();
            int xyear = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Last_Login_Datetime.Value.Year).SingleOrDefault();
            int xmonth = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Last_Login_Datetime.Value.Month).SingleOrDefault();
            int xday = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Last_Login_Datetime.Value.Day).SingleOrDefault();
            int xcounter = int.Parse(db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Counter).SingleOrDefault().ToString());
            xcounter++;
            var query = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"])).Select(u => u).ToList();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    db.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE [CRM].[dbo].[tbl_User_master] SET [Counter] = {0} WHERE Ref_no = {1}", xcounter, item.Ref_no);
                }
            }
            string c = (xcounter < 10) ? xcounter.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') : xcounter.ToString();
            string m = (xmonth < 10) ? xmonth.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') : xmonth.ToString();
            string d = (xday < 10) ? xday.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') : xday.ToString();
            return tickPrefix + xyear.ToString().Substring(3, 1) + m + d + c;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an expression like this:

```
xmonth < 10 ? xmonth.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') : xmonth.ToString()
```